# Laravelcollective use onclick

Tags: laravel

How to use construction like this?

```
 {{ Form::radio('name', 'yes', $attributes=['onclick'=>'show()'])  }}
```

Why 'onclick' doesn't work? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Pass attributes as 4th parameter:

```
{{ Form::radio('name', 'yes', null, ['onclick' => 'show()']) }}
```